# shared variable across multiple class instances that I can change outside the class

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

the code explains it better:

```
class Class{
  $var = 0;

  function getvar()
    echo $this->var;
  }

}



$inst1 = new Class();

// I want to change $var here to 5

$inst2 = new Class();

echo $inst2->getvar(); // should be 5
```

Is it possible

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Static. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

```
class MyClass {
    public static $var = 0;

    function setVar($value) {
        self::$var = $value;
    }

    function getVar() {
        return self::$var;
    }
}

echo MyClass::$var;
MyClass::setVar(1);
echo MyClass::getVar();  //Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this using a static member variable.

```
class foo {
  private static $var;

  public static setVar($value) {
    self::$var = $value;
  }

  public static getVar() {
    return self::$var;
  }
}

$a = new foo;
$a::setVar('bar');

$b = new foo;
echo $b::getVar();
// should echo 'bar';
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare `$var` to be [static](http://www.sunilb.com/php/php-5-tutorials-static-data-members-and-methods):

> A data member that is commonly
>   available to all objects of a class is
>   called a static member. Unlike regular
>   data members, static members share the
>   memory space between all objects of
>   the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variables:

```
class AAA{
  public static $var = 0;

  function getvar() {
    return AAA::$var;
  }

}

AAA::$var = "test";

$a1 = new AAA();
var_dump($a1->getvar());
var_dump(AAA::$var);
```